# Firebase Security Rules: Allow if user uid exists in a collection as a document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am collecting my admin users uid's as documents in "admins" collection. I want to allow users to read if they have their uid's in that collection as a document.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /admins/{document=**} {
      allow write; // Everyone should be able to write
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == ; // Only read if /admins/{youruid}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `exists()` to check if a document exists. Try refactoring your rules as shown below:

```
match /admins/{document=**} {
  allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid)); 
  // Only read if /admins/{youruid}
}
```

You can read more about `exists()` in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

Comment: This worked when I removed /admins/ from the match part. So I changed it to match /{document=**} {...}

Comment: @lowint `/admins/{document=**}` means the rule is applicable only for admins collection and it's sub-collections. Your current rule applies to all the collections then.

Comment: I fixed the current rule and added another rule for other needs. You were really helpful.

Comment: Would it still work if admins collecion is not readable by anyone? Thank you,